# What should be the curriculum for an adult piano lesson

Tags: theory, piano, lessons

I am an adult(37) learning piano with a teacher since 6 months. It is a 30 min lesson a week where each lesson, we go through a couple of pages of Nancy and Randall Faber's adult piano adventures. If I were to do a second lesson every week, what should be the content?

I feel the book does not give enough understanding of theory and composition, should the second lesson be exclusively piano music theory, or just plain music theory?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I don't rely on a particular book from which to make up lesson content. It's facile. There are so many facets to learning piano, from learning a scale, then having to make up a tune using it, harmonising it, sight-reading something in that key, etc., etc.

For me, every lesson must contain a different challenge, especially for adults, but kids like it as well. Problem for me with a 'lesson book' is that I can feel where the student needs to go next - the book doesn't have much idea, as we are all individuals.

The second lesson maybe should be with a different teacher with different views! Yes, theory is fine, but a section of theory with the practical approach following. Take a mode - Dorian. Find out where it came from, what it is, but then for homework, come up with a tune using the Dorian mode. Stuff like that.